# Possible combinations of lamb colour from parent

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just read the wikia that breeding yellow and red sheep would give orange lamb and also tried it.

So red + yellow = orange.

I wanted to ask what are other possible combinations?

Comment: I'm almost certain this is not the case. When breeding sheep, you will always get a sheep of the same color as one of the parents.

Comment: I tried it red + yellow = orange was successful

Comment: Hmm. Must be new in 1.8 or something.

Comment: I am using 1.7.2

Comment: Hmm.. this calls for some SCIENCE! I'll do some research when i get home in two hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Minecraft wiki article on sheep, in the breeding section breeding says:

> If the parents have 'compatible' wool colors  (meaning that the
>   corresponding dye items could  be combined into a third dye color),
>   the  resulting lamb will be a mix of their colors (e.g., blue sheep +
>   white sheep = light blue lamb).

Now, if you're confused on what "compatible" means, then look at the Dyeing article, which has this useful graphic:

[image: Minecraft Dye Chart]

Image source: http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/minecraft.gamepedia.com/b/b7/Minecraft-DyeGuide-1.7.2.png

Comment: Yes the chart shows me the answer i was looking for.